# what is regex for repeating same number 5 or more times for example 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444

Tags: sql-server, regex

what is regex for repeating same number 5 or more times for example 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444. I am using SQL server Like query

Comment: It might be helpful if you specified what language you're using.  Regex flavors are not universal.

Comment: I am using it in sql server

Comment: Did not try, posted no query nor sample data, did not explain goal, did not demonstrate any effort to investigate tsql support for regex (which is limited).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
(\d)\1{4,}
```

This is how it works:

[image]

This is the explanation from [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

```
1st Capturing Group (\d)
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
\1{4,} matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
{4,} Quantifier — Matches between 4 and unlimited times, as many times as 
possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line 
(not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: @chandreshpatel Please add more details to your question, including how you are using the regex in SQL server.

Comment: this is how I used it. select top 5 homephone from Test
where HomePhone like '%[(\d)\1{4,}]%'

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a Regex in SQL Server to accomplish what you are after.  You can reference this article that gives a great overview on using regular expressions in T-SQL with LIKE:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9106/using-regular-expressions-with-tsql-from-beginner-to-advanced/

For repeating characters with SQL Server, 2008+, you can use REPLICATE.

> [REPLICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):  Repeats a string value a specified number of times.

Base on previous comments you might be doing some sort of phone number evaluation.  Here's an example that might assist with what you are trying to accomplish:

```
DECLARE @PhoneNumbers TABLE
    (
        [HomePhone] NVARCHAR(500)
    );

INSERT INTO @PhoneNumbers (
                              [HomePhone]
                          )
VALUES ( N'123546789' )
     , ( N'111111111' )
     , ( N'555555555' )
     , ( N'222222222' )
     , ( N'231111123' )
     , ( N'897777712' )
     , ( N'010101010' )
     , ( N'333344444' )
     , ( N'123546789' );

SELECT *
FROM   @PhoneNumbers
WHERE  [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('1', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('2', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('3', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('4', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('5', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('6', 5) + '%'
       OR [HomePhone] LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('7', 5) + '%';
```

Thinking about this using REPLICATE in this situation probably won't gain you anything because there wouldn't be much difference between typing REPLICATE('1',5) as opposed to just typing it out '11111'.  But should give you an idea on functionality on repeating characters.

You had mentioned having the repeating items in the where clause isn't an option.  If ultimately all you're trying to evaluate is if the entire value of HomePhone is repeating, you can do that as follows:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM   @PhoneNumbers
    WHERE [HomePhone] = REPLICATE(LEFT([HomePhone],1), LEN([HomePhone]))
```

All that's happening here is it's taking the left most character HomehPhone, replicating for the length of the value and seeing if it matches.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want repetition like this thats why I need to use Regex

Comment: @chandreshpatel there won't be one for what you are trying to accomplish.  Regex for sql server is limited, you can check this out: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9106/using-regular-expressions-with-tsql-from-beginner-to-advanced/  but it won't solve specifically what you are after.   Closest you could get would be swap the where clause with "WHERE [HomePhone] = REPLICATE(LEFT([HomePhone],1), LEN([HomePhone]))", that's a one liner to check if the entire HomePhone is repeating or not.  I'll update my answer.